# Copy one form Data to another form Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

In my mvc4 web application I have to copy all the data of one form which have been saved previously to another newly created form. But when I copy the data using following code, all the data moves from one form to another and the data from previous form is deleted. Please specify why this is happening and how to copy that data.

```
  public FormEntity CopyFormData(CopyForm copyForm)
    {
        using (SIPSEntities db = new SIPSEntities())
        {

            if (db.QmsEvaluationForms.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Any(x => x.FormName == copyForm.FormName))
            {
                throw new Exception("Form Name Already Exists!");
            }
            else
            {
                var copyData = (from log in db.QmsEvaluationForms
                                where log.EvaluationFormId == copyForm.CopyFrom && log.IsActive == true
                                select new
                                {
                                    ZeroOnFatal = log.MakeScoreZeroOnFatal,
                                    FormControls = (from log1 in log.QmsEvaluationFormControls where log1.IsActive == true select log1).ToList(),
                                    FormParameters = (from log1 in log.QmsEvaluationParameters where log1.IsActive == true select log1).ToList()
                                }).FirstOrDefault();

                //Insert new form

                QmsEvaluationForm newForm = new QmsEvaluationForm();
                newForm.FormName = copyForm.FormName;
                newForm.MakeScoreZeroOnFatal = copyData.ZeroOnFatal;
                newForm.IsActive = true;
                newForm.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                newForm.SubprocessId = copyForm.SubProcessId;

                //(copy data from child table) this data is deleted from previous form and copied to another form
                newForm.QmsEvaluationFormControls = copyData.FormControls;

                //(copy data from child table) this data is deleted from previous form and copied to another form
                newForm.QmsEvaluationParameters = copyData.FormParameters;
                db.QmsEvaluationForms.Add(newForm);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return new FormEntity { FormId = newForm.EvaluationFormId, FormName = newForm.FormName, MakeZero = newForm.MakeScoreZeroOnFatal };


            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: When u mean form. U means HTML form. Cox the code below looks ok.

Comment: no the data from both child db tables is not copied but moves from previous form entity to the form entity .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem by debugging my code many times. what is happening here is when I copy he child table data to new form at

```
newForm.QmsEvaluationFormControls = copyData.FormControls;
```

and `newForm.QmsEvaluationParameters = copyData.FormParameters;`

the foreign key of each row is changed to new form's primary key. 
Now when I am copying the data by following method, every thing is working fine-

```
  public FormEntity CopyFormData(CopyForm copyForm)
    {
        using (SIPSEntities db = new SIPSEntities())
        {

            if (db.QmsEvaluationForms.Where(x => x.IsActive == true).Any(x => x.FormName == copyForm.FormName))
            {
                throw new Exception("Form Name Already Exists!");
            }
            else
            {

                var copyData = (from log in db.QmsEvaluationForms
                                 where log.EvaluationFormId == copyForm.CopyFrom && log.IsActive == true
                                 select log).FirstOrDefault();
                //Insert new form
                List<QmsEvaluationFormControl> cloneFormControlList = (from log1 in copyData.QmsEvaluationFormControls where log1.IsActive==true select log1).ToList();
                List<QmsEvaluationParameter> clonePaameterList = (from log1 in copyData.QmsEvaluationParameters where log1.IsActive == true select log1).ToList();
                QmsEvaluationForm newForm = new QmsEvaluationForm();
                newForm.FormName = copyForm.FormName;
                newForm.MakeScoreZeroOnFatal = copyData.MakeScoreZeroOnFatal;
                newForm.IsActive = true;
                newForm.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                newForm.SubprocessId = copyForm.SubProcessId;
               foreach(var control in cloneFormControlList){
                   QmsEvaluationFormControl controlData=new QmsEvaluationFormControl();
                   controlData.Caption=control.Caption;
                   controlData.CreatedOn=DateTime.Now;
                   controlData.FieldTypeId=control.FieldTypeId;
                   controlData.FormValidationParameterId=control.FormValidationParameterId;
                   controlData.ListNameId=control.ListNameId;
                   controlData.IsMandatory=control.IsMandatory;
                   controlData.MaxSize=control.MaxSize;
                   controlData.IsActive=control.IsActive;
                   newForm.QmsEvaluationFormControls.Add(controlData);

               }

               foreach (var parameter in clonePaameterList)
               {
                   QmsEvaluationParameter parameterData = new QmsEvaluationParameter();
                   parameterData.Category = parameter.Category;
                   parameterData.ParameteerCode = parameter.ParameteerCode;
                   parameterData.EvaluationParameter = parameter.EvaluationParameter;
                   parameterData.ListNameId = parameter.ListNameId;
                   parameterData.CriticalTypeId = parameter.CriticalTypeId;
                   parameterData.Weightage = parameter.Weightage;
                   parameterData.IsActive = parameter.IsActive;
                   parameterData.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                   newForm.QmsEvaluationParameters.Add(parameterData);
               }
                db.QmsEvaluationForms.Add(newForm);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return new FormEntity { FormId = newForm.EvaluationFormId, FormName = newForm.FormName, MakeZero = newForm.MakeScoreZeroOnFatal };


            }


        }
    }
```